# bcdedit - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: windows-7, bcd, bcdedit

This is a strange one, but whenever I `bcdedit /export` and then try to load it with `bcdedit /store`, system seems to swallow up the file, and you can't unlock it or close the handle on process explorer.

It's not like it does this after you've viewed the BCD store, it doesn't even let you view it the first time.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m07dB8Wc_uI)

Comment: I'm assuming you're an administrator on the system, correct?  What CLI shell are you using?  Have you tried closing bcdedit (and the CLI shell) after /export, then restart bcdedit and attempt to load it with /store?  Have you tried exporting the file to the local OS drive C:?  Also, try temporarily disabling any active anti-virus scanning.  Just some thoughts.

Comment: @leeharvey1 When you reboot or unplug the USB drive the files become available again and then when you run bcdedit /store, it still doesn't work, and the same issue occurs with cmd.exe.  Windows firewall is off and I don't have an antivirus. It is a new windows 7 with windows update up to date